# Unable to process function body node type: ArrowFunctionExpression

Tags: babeljs, jestjs, istanbul

I run tests with Jest. The tests pass but it shows this line:

```
Unable to process function body node type: ArrowFunctionExpression
```

Why is it there and how to remove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like a compatibilty problem between babel@7 and istanbul-lib-instrument https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/issues/119